# Laravel 8 - Get route via Curl that is behind login

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `Laravel Framework 8.47.0`.

I am trying to access a private API from my laravel application via a wordpress script. The API is behind a login and in my laravel application. Find below my `web.php` file:

```
Route::group(
    ['middleware' => 'user'],
    function () {
       Route::get('hiddenApi', 'APIController@returnData')->name('hiddenAPI');
    }
);
```

As you can see, you need `user` credentials to access this route.

I have tried to create the following code to log in via curl and access the API:

```php
$BASE_URL = "https://mywebsite.com/";
$module = "";

try {
    // get json file from api
    $link = $BASE_URL . "hiddenApi";
    $username = 'system@system.com';
    $password = 'systemPassword';

    $channel = curl_init();

    // Debugging
    // curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $link);

    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); // never times out during transfer
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $output = curl_exec($channel);
    $info = curl_getinfo($channel);
...
```

When executing the above code from my wordpress application I get as output the `login`-page.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: It's not easy to guess what you are doing from above code. It would be helpful to include what you are trying to do. Are you trying to login into site? Are you trying to mimik login post request? What is it?

Comment: well, I even don't know if there is a way to login via `CURLOPT_USERPWD` on Laravel

Comment: well, if you're trying to access `https://mywebsite.com/login` to log in the system with `CURLOPT_USERPWD`, so I think that you are going to the wrong way, because when you're using `GET` method this will be the route of the login-page, if you change to `POST` method this will be the true login end-point

Comment: @DaviMendesDev Yes I am trying to log in via curl and THEN access the route. I am currently struggling to login.

Comment: @RajeshPaudel Sorry. Please see my updated answer!